# filter on a foreign key value django

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I'm struggling getting the right query for my project. Here is an example of my model :

```
from django.db import models

class Product_Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    handle = models.SlugField(max_length=30, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    collection = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    collections = models.ManyToManyField('Collection')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Product_Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.product_id
```

I am trying to get all the product_id based on the value of the `Product_Category.collection`.

Eg: books is a `Product_category.collection`, I want to get all the products for books collection.

I tried __ method also. Somehow it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The double underscore is the way to go.

```
books = Product.objects.filter(category__collection='books')
```

Comment: so i need to use the field name in the product table __ then field name in the Product_Category.. it does not work.. I tried

Comment: Doesn't work *how*? What happens when you try? Show the exact code, as well as the data you have in the table.